# Removing specific map/object from array in firebase

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experimenting with arrays and maps/objects in firestore. I wondered how can I remove a specific map from the array. 
I tried something like this:

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(interestedInID).get().then((val){
  return val.data['usersInterested'].removeWhere((item)=>
    item['userID'] == userID
  ); 
}).catchError((e){
  print(e);
});
```

but I get this error in terminal:

```
Unsupported operation: Cannot remove from a fixed-length list
```

I don't really understand what it means. I did some googling and fixed-length list is exactly what it says. It's a list that has a fixed length and it can't be changed, but fixed-length list has to be declared explicitly. Growable list on the other hand doesn't need to be declared. 
I haven't declared the fixed-length list in my firestore, yet it keeps saying that I can't remove elements from it. I can add / push elements however and remove them using:

```
'key': FieldValue.arrayRemove([value])
```

but I can't figure out how to remove the element based on a specific condition. In this case an userID.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @Andrey.
Was quite a long time ago, but I posted the solution that worked for me, but it showed I deleted it. I don't know why, so I undeleted the post. Can you see it underneath?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(interestedInID).updateData({
  'usersInterested': FieldValue.arrayRemove([{}.remove(userID)])
});
```

I'm not sure, but I think get() simply allows you to read the document, but doesn't allow to make any changes to it. 
Anyways, now it works

Answer (score 0):

This may be a workaround:

1. You fetch your specific `Array` with key: values from Firebase
2. Put that in a temporary reference `List` in dart
3. Remove your specific `Map` from the reference `List`, like you did before
4. Update data in Firebase like so:

```
// make a reference List
List<Map> _modifiedUsersInterested = List();

// ... (fetch your Array first from Firebase, put those items in the reference List)

// remove the right Map from the reference List
_modifiedUsersInterested.removeWhere((item) => {
    item['userID'] == userID
});

// set the reference List as your array in Firebase
await Firestore.instance
.collection('users')
.document(interestedInId)
.updateData(
    {'usersInterested': _modifiedUsersInterested}
);
```

Comment: did you actually confirm that this method works? Either way, there should be a much simpler way to do this without reading and then resaving the entire list minus the removed value.